# To implement new type ACL in joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am creating one component for managing leads[leads or client leads are submitted from front end],in this component i want to implement a ACL like this.

My client requirement...

```
SuperAdmin
|—  Manager
|—|— Administrator
```

*consider `Administrator` is under `Manager`.Please dont compare with joomla default ACL.*

All leads are show to superadmin.Superadmin will assign the leads to other users.

If the logged in user is a `Manager`,he able to see all user leads those who are under `Manager` group & `Administrator` group.

If the logged in user is a `Administrator`,he have no permission for to see others leads because administrator haven't any sub groups,its the last group.

I am using the following query

```
$query->select( 'c.id as groupid,c.title AS group_name');
$query->from('#__usergroups AS c');
$query->join('LEFT', '#__usergroups AS s ON (s.lft <= c.lft AND s.rgt >= c.rgt) OR (s.lft > c.lft AND s.rgt < c.rgt)' );
$query->where('s.id = "'.$UG.'"');
$query->order('c.lft');
$db->setquery($query);
$gids           = $db->loadResultArray();
$gids           = implode(",",$gids);
```

`$UG` => logged in user groupid.

If logged in user is `Manager`,`$UG` is `6`

**OUTPUT**

```
 groupid    group_name
   1         Public
   6         Manager
   7         Administrator
```

If logged in user is `Administrator`,`$UG` is `7`.Its also return same answer....I want the output as

If the `Manager` logged in

**OUTPUT Will be**

```
 groupid    group_name
   6      Manager
   7     Administrator
```

If the `Administrator` logged in

**OUTPUT Will be**

```
 groupid    group_name
   7    Administrator
```

or empty

Any one please help me....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i found the answer

Added line **`AND s.lft <= c.lft AND s.rgt >= c.rgt`** in `where` condition

```
$query->select( 'c.id as groupid,c.title AS group_name');
$query->from('#__usergroups AS c');
$query->join('LEFT', '#__usergroups AS s ON (s.lft <= c.lft AND s.rgt >= c.rgt) OR (s.lft > c.lft AND s.rgt < c.rgt)' );
$query->where('s.id = "'.$UG.'" AND s.lft <= c.lft AND s.rgt >= c.rgt ');
$query->order('c.lft');
$db->setquery($query);
$gids           = $db->loadResultArray();
```

[image]